# Constraint PCL ICP output from 6dof to only 3dof Translations

Tags: c++, ros, point-cloud-library

I would like to implement pcl icp for 2 sets of pointcloud. However the problem surfaced when i would like to further add some constraint to fix the rotational axis in the 3d space. I realized that I can constraint it to a 3dof (1rotation and 2 translations) by this: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/tools/icp2d.cpp

However if i would like to make custom constraints on some specific dof, is it possible?? (e.g. remove all 3 -axis rotation)

P/s: Can it  be done with `pcl::registration::TransformationEstimationLM`, which can be furtheer `icp.setTransformationEstimation (te)`?

Comment: icp is a pretty straight forward algorithm.  You could write a gradient decent based on 3 axis of translation yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Regards to this, I managed to constraint it by having my own `WrapPoingRigid6D.h`, which is a modification of `<pcl/registration/warp_point_rigid_6d.h>`

The modification is as below:

```
  void 
  setParam (const VectorX & p) override
  {
    assert (p.rows () == this->getDimension ());

    // Copy the rotation and translation components
    transform_matrix_.setZero ();
    transform_matrix_.setIdentity ();   
    transform_matrix_ (0, 3) = p[0];
    transform_matrix_ (1, 3) = p[1];
    transform_matrix_ (2, 3) = p[2];
  }
```

After creating my own `WarpPointRigid3DTrans`, pass it to pcl icp by:

```
  WarpPointRigid3DTrans<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr warp_fcn 
    (new camera_lib::WarpPointRigid3DTrans<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ>);
  pcl::registration::TransformationEstimationLM<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr te 
    (new pcl::registration::TransformationEstimationLM<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ>);
  te->setWarpFunction (warp_fcn);
  icp.setTransformationEstimation (te);
```

This will work as needed. Thus have your own custom `wrappointrigid` to cater your need. Cheers!